# why is my multi wallet still showing sending /unconfirmed?

Tags: wallet, multibit

My wallet received bitcoin successfully but it's showing unconfirmed in my end and the other transactions i have sent wouldn't go through .

It's been showing sending for over 24hrs and the address sent to still haven't received the amounts in their wallets.

I need help with this asap please. I am going to attach a screenshot to better understand my predicament.[image]